# Resize /home on CentOS vmware guest

Tags: centos, partition, hard-disk, vmware

I have a new vmware guest, let's say I want to extend it from 100 GB to 300 GB

My question is **how to insert all the 200gb into `/home`? Where can I start?**

`df -h` displays:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `gparted`. It's a great GUI front-end to `parted`. It should be able to help you there.

Comment: @JosephR. how can i install parted and gparted? cant find it

Comment: ah got it from epel, testing it

Comment: I was just about to post [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/156156/how-to-install-gparted-on-centos) before you found it. I'm putting it here for future readers.

Comment: warning gtk error

Comment: Either start it from the GUI menu or use `su -` when starting it from the terminal

Comment: gtk-warning cannot open display, its a barebone server centos 6.4 no gui can weuse parted?

Comment: Yes, in this case you can't use `gparted` and will have to settle for `parted`. I'm afraid I have only relied on `gparted` in the past and therefore can't help you with `parted`.

Comment: Please , give us output of `vgs` command

Comment: which version of vmware you are using vmware workstation or vmware server or esxi ?

Comment: Its the latest 5.5